# Adding beforeSend to backbone ajax calls

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

I would like to add a beforeSend property to every ajax call that backbone makes.

Is the way to go about this in overriding sync or Backbone.ajax?

Answer (score 2):

This worked to do what I wanted.

```
  Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var type = methodMap[method];

    var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', type);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
        if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    ...
```